# Android Eclipse update Error?

Tags: android, eclipse

Just now update to my eclipse to latest version, showing this error(ADT XML Overlay 23.0.3.1327240) .Any one have idea of this.

[image]

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
Software currently installed: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
ADT XML Overlay 23.0.3.1327240 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.3.1327240)
ADT XML Overlay 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.3.1327240]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
```

Comment: Redownload the eclipse. This is the common problem in this update

Comment: Redownload means All eclipse versions.

Comment: Download Android SDK from Android website and replace with your old eclipse and select your old workplace
this will update your eclipse and your data will not be lost as well. I did too. no risk

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by uninstalling the plugin that was causing the conflicting dependency (Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)

> Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details. On the "Installed
>   software" tab click on the software that you wish to uninstall, then
>   click the "Uninstall..." button.

And then install the ADT plugin again (with Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240):

> 1. Select *Help* > *Install New Software*
> 2. *Work with:* p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
> 3. Select *Developer Tools* and *Next*
> 4. *Next*, Accept the license agreement* and *Finish*

Note: Also removed the plugin App Engine for Android (that got me dependency problem with ADT as well)